# Answering the Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters in Kotlin

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, data-structures, hashset

I've spend some time working on the problem and got this close

```
 fun lengthOfLongestSubstring(s: String): Int {
        var set = HashSet<Char>()
        var initalChar = 0
        var count = 0
        
        s.forEach {r ->
            while(!set.add(s[r]))
            set.remove(s[r])
            initalChar++
            set.add(s[r])
            count = maxOf(count, r - initialChar + 1)
            
        }
        return count
    }
```

I understand that a HashSet is needed to answer the question since it doesn't allow for repeating characters but I keep getting a type mismatch error. I'm not above being wrong. Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: `r` is a character, not a position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your misunderstanding is that `r` represents a character in the string, not an index of the string, so saying `s[r]` doesn't make sense. You just mean `r`.

But you are also using `r` on its own, so you should be using `forEachIndexed`, which lets you access both the element of the sequence and the index of that element:

```
s.forEach { i, r ->
    while(!set.add(r))
        set.remove(r)
    initialChar++
    set.add(r)
    count = maxOf(count, i - initialChar + 1)
    
}
```

Though there are still some parts of your code that doesn't quite make sense.

`while(!set.add(r)) set.remove(r)` is functionally the same as `set.add(r)`. If `add` returns false, that means the element is already in the set, you remove it and the next iteration of the loop adds the element back into the set. If `add` returns true, that means the set didn't have the element and it was successfully added, so in any case, the result is you add `r` to the set.

And then you do `set.add(r)` *again* two lines later for some reason?

Anyway, here is a brute-force solution that you can use as a starting point to optimise:

```
fun lengthOfLongestSubstring(s: String): Int {
    val set = mutableSetOf<Char>()
    var currentMax = 0
    // for each substring starting at index i...
    for (i in s.indices) {
        // update the current max from the previous iterations...
        currentMax = maxOf(currentMax, set.size)
        // clear the set to record a new substring
        set.clear()

        // loop through the characters in this substring
        for (j in i..s.lastIndex) {
            if (!set.add(s[j])) { // if the letter already exists
                break // go to the next iteration of the outer for loop
            }
        }
    }
    return maxOf(currentMax, set.size)
}
```